# How to show the numbers that is divisible by 4 in Haskell Language?

Tags: haskell

The target is to use filter statemate to show the numbers in [1..20] that is divisible by 4. Return a list only with the number that is divisible by 4.

I'm using `mod` as

```
  filter (\x -> (x `mod` 4 == x))[1..20]
```

but this only returns [1,2,3]
What do I suppose to do with this?

Comment: Your condition should be `mod x 4 == 0`

Comment: `[4,8..20]` Hahaha but it works to any higher value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filter (\x -> (x `mod` 4) == 0) [1..20]
```